# how can fix the error that open_price equal to close_price when resample data by clickhouse time function?

Tags: sql, clickhouse, ohlc

```
        query_sql = f"""
           WITH 
               toDateTime('{start.date()} 21:00:00') AS StartTimestamp, 
               toDateTime('{end_date} 15:00:00') AS EndTimestamp
           SELECT 
                local_symbol,
               max(last_price) AS high_price,
               min(last_price) AS low_price,
               argMax(last_price, toUnixTimestamp(fast)) as close_price ,
               argMin(last_price, toUnixTimestamp(fast)) as open_price,
               sum(volume) AS volume,
               sum(amount) AS amount
           FROM tick
           WHERE (datetime >= StartTimestamp) AND (datetime <= EndTimestamp) AND local_symbol='{symbol}'
--            GROUP BY toStartOfInterval(datetime, INTERVAL {n} minute ) as fast,local_symbol
         GROUP BY toStartOfMinute(datetime) as fast,local_symbol
           ORDER BY fast ASC
               """
```

Here is my SQL code,  and I want to get the open_price, high_price, low_price, close_price, but I the result by the SQL did not meet expectations

**The open_price is always equal to  close_price**, and others correct.

```
{'local_symbol': 'rb2010.CTP', 'high_price': 3828.0, 'low_price': 3826.0, 'close_price': 3827.0, 'open_price': 3827.0, 'volume': 409, 'amount': 15653230.0, '_database': <infi.clickhouse_orm.database.Database object at 0x0000022EF5C95408>}
{'local_symbol': 'rb2010.CTP', 'high_price': 3828.0, 'low_price': 3826.0, 'close_price': 3827.0, 'open_price': 3827.0, 'volume': 357, 'amount': 13663860.0, '_database': <infi.clickhouse_orm.database.Database object at 0x0000022EF5C95408>}
{'local_symbol': 'rb2010.CTP', 'high_price': 3828.0, 'low_price': 3825.0, 'close_price': 3827.0, 'open_price': 3827.0, 'volume': 1058, 'amount': 40483280.0, '_database': <infi.clickhouse_orm.database.Database object at 0x0000022EF5C95408>}
{'local_symbol': 'rb2010.CTP', 'high_price': 3828.0, 'low_price': 3825.0, 'close_price': 3826.0, 'open_price': 3826.0, 'volume': 972, 'amount': 37193310.0, '_database': <infi.clickhouse_orm.database.Database object at 0x0000022EF5C95408>}
{'local_symbol': 'rb2010.CTP', 'high_price': 3828.0, 'low_price': 3826.0, 'close_price': 3828.0, 'open_price': 3828.0, 'volume': 643, 'amount': 24608060.0, '_database': <infi.clickhouse_orm.database.Database object at 0x0000022EF5C95408>}
{'local_symbol': 'rb2010.CTP', 'high_price': 3828.0, 'low_price': 3826.0, 'close_price': 3827.0, 'open_price': 3827.0, 'volume': 739, 'amount': 28276760.0, '_database': <infi.clickhouse_orm.database.Database object at 0x0000022EF5C95408>}
{'local_symbol': 'rb2010.CTP', 'high_price': 3828.0, 'low_price': 3827.0, 'close_price': 3828.0, 'open_price': 3828.0, 'volume': 118, 'amount': 4516640.0, '_database': <infi.clickhouse_orm.database.Database object at 0x0000022EF5C95408>}
{'local_symbol': 'rb2010.CTP', 'high_price': 3828.0, 'low_price': 3826.0, 'close_price': 3828.0, 'open_price': 3828.0, 'volume': 678, 'amount': 25949650.0, '_database': <infi.clickhouse_orm.database.Database object at 0x0000022EF5C95408>}
{'local_symbol': 'rb2010.CTP', 'high_price': 3829.0, 'low_price': 3827.0, 'close_price': 3827.0, 'open_price': 3827.0, 'volume': 1009, 'amount': 38630160.0, '_database': <infi.clickhouse_orm.database.Database object at 0x0000022EF5C95408>}
{'local_symbol': 'rb2010.CTP', 'high_price': 3831.0, 'low_price': 3829.0, 'close_price': 3830.0, 'open_price': 3830.0, 'volume': 1798, 'amount': 68865630.0, '_database': <infi.clickhouse_orm.database.Database object at 0x0000022EF5C95408>}
{'local_symbol': 'rb2010.CTP', 'high_price': 3831.0, 'low_price': 3829.0, 'close_price': 3830.0, 'open_price': 3830.0, 'volume': 1039, 'amount': 39797350.0, '_database': <infi.clickhouse_orm.database.Database object at 0x0000022EF5C95408>}
```

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it by using `argMin(last_price, toUnixTimestamp(datetime)) as open_price`,